# BufferedReader to byte[]

Tags: android, bufferedreader

Need to load image to a byte[] variable.

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), body + ".image");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

How can I convert `BufferedReader` to `byte[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Reader` is meant for converting bytes into characters. That is not what you want here.  You need an `InputStream` instead.  You can then `read()` from the stream to your `byte[]` array as needed, eg:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), body + ".image");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
byte[] buf = new byte[file.length()];
int numRead = in.read(buf);
```

Comment: Where do you get `number of bytes needed`? Possible to get from `in`?

Comment: @János if your goal is to load the entire file into the `byte[]` you can use the `file.length()` method.